# how to generate .aab from project flutter

Tags: flutter, google-play

i want to generate an .aab file from flutter project using this command

```
flutter build appbundle

 Building with sound null safety 

Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 1224KB to 1154KB: Removed 5%
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             47.8s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab (21.7MB).
```

to put it in play.google.com  but i get this problem

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug
> mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode

so  in the file android/app/build.gradle i did some modification

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

but i get the same problem the .aab is in debug mode and not in release mode how to do it to upload the application in play store ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign the app and use the release version, not the debug.
Their web page explains how: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app